# Bootstrap 3.2: When added checkbox with jQuery, it not going to visible with proper css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have used the bootstrap 3.2.

I want to add the checkbox using jQuery.

I have used the following html to append in div with id "all_deal_type".

Here is the div html

```
       <div class="col-md-10 pull-right" style="padding-left:0px;" id="all_deal_type"</div>
```

Here is the html template which I used to append in the div.

```
    var template =  '<div class="col-md-3">'
                        +'<div class="form-group">'
                            +'<div class="checkbox-list">'
                                +'<label>'
                                +'<input type="checkbox" value="'+i+'"> '+v+'</label>'
                                +'<label>'
                            +'</div>'
                        +'</div>'
                    +'</div>';
     $("#all_deal_type").append(template);
```

when I append the checkbox html it does not show as bootstrap do with the checkbox.

Can you please guide me where I am wrong?

Comment: is it a custom theme you have purchased or just plain bootstrap theme which you have built?

Comment: just plain bootstrap, I am building.

Comment: are you planning on adding multiple checkboxes in a div with jquery  or one one checkbox in a form group as shown above

Answer (score 1):

change html formatting

```
<div class="form-group checkbox-list col-md-9" style="padding-left:0px;" id="all_deal_type">
</div>
```

change jquery to

```
var template =  '<div class="checkbox col-md-3">'
                      +'<label>'
                      +'<input type="checkbox" value="'+i+'">' 
                      +v+'</label>'
                +'</div>';
$("#all_deal_type").append(template);`
```

Comment: What is the difference between code I have added in question and your answer?

Comment: i think you error is due to a typo. when i tried above code i got  result the way i wanted it

Comment: In my case the checkbox get added there but does not look like the boostrap vuew for the checkbox.

Comment: try the current code. also `pull-right` will float the div to right. what u mean by `like the boostrap view`

Comment: check the updated answer. remove `col-md-3` if you want to display it as a list

Comment: No, My problem is that: when we add options in select in boostrap we refresh the select so that bootstrap get applied to it. Here same case is, I want to know How could I add the checkboxes on fly with bootstrap.

Comment: setup a jsfiddle for you issue, its much easier to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

try adding `checkbox` class to `form-group` div or `checkbox-list` div